# Excel formula to find the latest cost matching to an Item number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula that will allow me to get the latest cost attached to a specific MPN from a list that has multiple cost for the same MPN from different dates.

Anyone up to the challenge?

See picture bellow for the data!

Data

[image]

Comment: If you have excel 365, use `FILTER` to filter your table, then use `SORT` to get the latest date first. Finally, use `INDEX` to return the first result.

Comment: Very true, but INDEX could be replaced with `@`, which would return the first value.

Comment: @P.b I thought the same thing but you would need to include the date column in the return of the FILTER so you can SORT on it.  Using the `@` would return all the values in the first line not just the unit cost.

Comment: You're correct. It'll spill the first result of both columns that are being filtered / sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUMIFS with MAXIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,F2,B:B,MAXIFS(B:B,C:C,F2))
```

if one does not have MAXIFS:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,F2,B:B,AGGREGATE(14,7,B:B/(C:C=F2),1))
```

Or if you have Office 365.  Like Dave Thunes commented:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(B:D,C:C=F2),1,-1),1,3)
```

Comment: Thanks @Scott! =SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,F2,B:B,MAXIFS(B:B,C:C,F2))  worked!!